# passing object to angularjs directive from the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Trying to get my head around AngularJS directives. I need to pass a full object from my main controller to the directive. See the code below and jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/Z5MBf/4/

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MandatCtrl">
    <div person myPerson="mandat.person"></div>

    <span>{{mandat.rum}}</span>
    <span>{{mandat.person.firstname}}</span>

</div>
```

and the script:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("MandatCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.mandat = { rum: "15000", person: { id: 1408, firstname: "sam" } };
});

myApp.directive("person", function () {     
return {
    scope: {
        myPerson: "="
    },
    template: 'test: <div ng-model="myPerson"><input type="text" ng-model="firstname" /></div>'
}
});
```

Ok, the binding is working fine for mandat.rum and mandat.person.firstname.

However, I'm trying to pass mandat.person to the directive, and it does not work. I know I must be doing something wrong, the question is what ? :)

Comment: A general note: Please don't mix Swedish and English in your code. The syntax is in english, keep your code in english without mixing. It just makes it harder to understand, even though swedish is my native language.

Comment: I wish I spoke Swedish :p   Where do you see any Swedish in my code ???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pls see below working copy

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <span>{{mandat.rum}}</span>
      <span>{{mandat.person.firstname}}</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="mandat.person.firstname" />
    <my-directive mandateperson="mandat.person" >

      </my-directive>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.mandat = { name: "John", surname: "Doe", person: { id: 1408, firstname: "sam" } };
        });


        app.directive('myDirective', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: "<div><span>{{mandateperson.id}}<span><input type='text' ng-model='mandateperson.firstname' /></div>",
                replace: true,
                scope: { mandateperson: '=' }
                }
            }
        )
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cool, that works. But I can't see what's wrong with my code. Could you point me to what I was doing wrong ? You're not doing exactly the same way as you are using restrict: 'E' but that can't be the reason your code is working, or can it ?

Comment: I think it is because you must encapsulate your properties within an object. So instead of doing : <input type='text' ng-model='firstname' /> you must do <input type='text' ng-model='myPerson.firstname' />

Comment: it doesn't seem to be that, I've tried both ways and none of them work for me.

Comment: 1) use myperson.firstname 2)replace camel case in attribute and scope just replace myperson with myPerson and it will work

Comment: oh yeah I just figured it out ! So does this mean all scope objects have to be lower case ? that's annoying...

Comment: Ah, got it. If I do myPerson in the scope, then the attribute should be my-person. I had forgotten about that... Still learning...

Comment: @AjayBeniwal what if my data comes from api , value not defined in controller as yours? once after directive have finished loading . how to get update value reflect in directive

Comment: @AjayBeniwal, some explanatory text would make this a much better answer.