# calling method of parent controller from a directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990122/passing-object-to-angularjs-directive-from-the-controller), I'm now trying to call a method on the parent controller from my directive. I get an undefined parameter. Here's what I do:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <span>{{mandat.rum}}</span>
  <span>{{mandat.surname}}</span>
<input type="text" ng-model="mandat.person.firstname" />
<my-directive mandate-person="mandat.person" updateparent="updatePerson()" >

  </my-directive>
</body>
```

And the script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.mandat = { name: "John", surname: "Doe", person: { id: 1408, firstname: "sam" } };
        $scope.updatePerson = function(person) {
            alert(person.firstname);
          $scope.mandat.person = person;   
        }
    });


    app.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<div><span>{{mandatePerson.id}}<span><input type='text' ng-model='mandatePerson.firstname' /><button ng-click='updateparent({person: mandatePerson})'>click</button></div>",
            replace: true,
            scope: { mandatePerson: '=', updateparent: '&' }
            }
        }
    )
```

when the updatePerson method gets called, person is undefined.

jsfiddle here :  http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/Z5MBf/7/

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just simple change your html as below

```
<my-directive mandate-person="mandat.person" updateparent="updatePerson(person)" >

      </my-directive>
```

you are not passing "person" with updatePerson thats why it is not working

Comment: so what I'm doing is the correct way for updating the parent scope, right ? I just forgot to pass "person".

Comment: To anyone else who was initially confused by this: notice the object notation in the ng-click within the template: `ng-click='updateparent({person: mandatePerson})'`

Answer (score 38):

Accessing controller method means accessing a method on parent scope from directive controller/link/scope.

If the directive is sharing/inheriting the parent scope then it is quite straight forward to just invoke a parent scope method.

Little more work is required when you want to access parent scope method from Isolated directive scope.

There are few options (may be more than listed below) to invoke a parent scope method from isolated directives scope or watch parent scope variables (**option#6** specially).

*Note* that I used `link function` in these examples but you can use a `directive controller` as well based on requirement.

**Option#1.** **Through Object literal and from directive html template**

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <p> Directive Content</p>
    <sd-items-filter selected-items="selectedItems" selected-items-changed="selectedItemsChanged(selectedItems)" items="items"> </sd-items-filter>


    <P style="color:red">Selected Items (in parent controller) set to: {{selectedItemsReturnedFromDirective}} </p>

  </body>

</html>
```

**`itemfilterTemplate.html`**

```
<select ng-model="selectedItems" multiple="multiple" style="height: 200px; width: 250px;" ng-change="selectedItemsChanged({selectedItems:selectedItems})" ng-options="item.id as item.name group by item.model for item in items | orderBy:'name'">
  <option>--</option>
</select>
```

**`app.js`**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('sdItemsFilter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      items: '=',
      selectedItems: '=',
      selectedItemsChanged: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: "itemfilterTemplate.html"
  }
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'TARS';

  $scope.selectedItems = ["allItems"];

  $scope.selectedItemsChanged = function(selectedItems1) {
    $scope.selectedItemsReturnedFromDirective = selectedItems1;
  }

  $scope.items = [{
    "id": "allItems",
    "name": "All Items",
    "order": 0
  }, {
    "id": "CaseItem",
    "name": "Case Item",
    "model": "PredefinedModel"
  }, {
    "id": "Application",
    "name": "Application",
    "model": "Bank"
    }]

});
```

working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/rgKUsYGDo9O3tewL6xgr?p=preview

**Option#2. Through Object literal and from directive link/scope**

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <p> Directive Content</p>
    <sd-items-filter selected-items="selectedItems" selected-items-changed="selectedItemsChanged(selectedItems)" items="items"> </sd-items-filter>


    <P style="color:red">Selected Items (in parent controller) set to: {{selectedItemsReturnedFromDirective}} </p>

  </body>

</html>
```

**`itemfilterTemplate.html`**

```
<select ng-model="selectedItems" multiple="multiple" style="height: 200px; width: 250px;" 
 ng-change="selectedItemsChangedDir()" ng-options="item.id as item.name group by item.model for item in items | orderBy:'name'">
  <option>--</option>
</select>
```

**`app.js`**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('sdItemsFilter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      items: '=',
      selectedItems: '=',
      selectedItemsChanged: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: "itemfilterTemplate.html",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs){
      scope.selectedItemsChangedDir = function(){
        scope.selectedItemsChanged({selectedItems:scope.selectedItems});  
      }
    }
  }
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'TARS';

  $scope.selectedItems = ["allItems"];

  $scope.selectedItemsChanged = function(selectedItems1) {
    $scope.selectedItemsReturnedFromDirective = selectedItems1;
  }

  $scope.items = [{
    "id": "allItems",
    "name": "All Items",
    "order": 0
  }, {
    "id": "CaseItem",
    "name": "Case Item",
    "model": "PredefinedModel"
  }, {
    "id": "Application",
    "name": "Application",
    "model": "Bank"
    }]
});
```

working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/BRvYm2SpSpBK9uxNIcTa?p=preview

**Option#3. Through Function reference and from directive html template**

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <p> Directive Content</p>
    <sd-items-filter selected-items="selectedItems" selected-items-changed="selectedItemsChanged" items="items"> </sd-items-filter>


    <P style="color:red">Selected Items (in parent controller) set to: {{selectedItemsReturnFromDirective}} </p>

  </body>

</html>
```

**`itemfilterTemplate.html`**

```
<select ng-model="selectedItems" multiple="multiple" style="height: 200px; width: 250px;" 
 ng-change="selectedItemsChanged()(selectedItems)" ng-options="item.id as item.name group by item.model for item in items | orderBy:'name'">
  <option>--</option>
</select>
```

**`app.js`**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('sdItemsFilter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      items: '=',
      selectedItems:'=',
      selectedItemsChanged: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: "itemfilterTemplate.html"
  }
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'TARS';

  $scope.selectedItems = ["allItems"];

  $scope.selectedItemsChanged = function(selectedItems1) {
    $scope.selectedItemsReturnFromDirective = selectedItems1;
  }

  $scope.items = [{
    "id": "allItems",
    "name": "All Items",
    "order": 0
  }, {
    "id": "CaseItem",
    "name": "Case Item",
    "model": "PredefinedModel"
  }, {
    "id": "Application",
    "name": "Application",
    "model": "Bank"
    }]
});
```

working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jo6FcYfVXCCg3vH42BIz?p=preview

**Option#4. Through Function reference and from directive link/scope**

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <p> Directive Content</p>
    <sd-items-filter selected-items="selectedItems" selected-items-changed="selectedItemsChanged" items="items"> </sd-items-filter>


    <P style="color:red">Selected Items (in parent controller) set to: {{selectedItemsReturnedFromDirective}} </p>

  </body>

</html>
```

**`itemfilterTemplate.html`**

```
<select ng-model="selectedItems" multiple="multiple" style="height: 200px; width: 250px;" ng-change="selectedItemsChangedDir()" ng-options="item.id as item.name group by item.model for item in items | orderBy:'name'">
  <option>--</option>
</select>
```

**`app.js`**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('sdItemsFilter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      items: '=',
      selectedItems: '=',
      selectedItemsChanged: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: "itemfilterTemplate.html",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs){
      scope.selectedItemsChangedDir = function(){
        scope.selectedItemsChanged()(scope.selectedItems);  
      }
    }
  }
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'TARS';

  $scope.selectedItems = ["allItems"];

  $scope.selectedItemsChanged = function(selectedItems1) {
    $scope.selectedItemsReturnedFromDirective = selectedItems1;
  }

  $scope.items = [{
    "id": "allItems",
    "name": "All Items",
    "order": 0
  }, {
    "id": "CaseItem",
    "name": "Case Item",
    "model": "PredefinedModel"
  }, {
    "id": "Application",
    "name": "Application",
    "model": "Bank"
    }]

});
```

working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/BSqx2J1yCY86IJwAnQF1?p=preview

**Option#5: Through ng-model and two way binding, you can update parent scope variables.**. So, you may not require to invoke parent scope functions in some cases.

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <p> Directive Content</p>
    <sd-items-filter ng-model="selectedItems" selected-items-changed="selectedItemsChanged" items="items"> </sd-items-filter>


    <P style="color:red">Selected Items (in parent controller) set to: {{selectedItems}} </p>

  </body>

</html>
```

**`itemfilterTemplate.html`**

```
<select ng-model="selectedItems" multiple="multiple" style="height: 200px; width: 250px;" 
 ng-options="item.id as item.name group by item.model for item in items | orderBy:'name'">
  <option>--</option>
</select>
```

**`app.js`**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('sdItemsFilter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      items: '=',
      selectedItems: '=ngModel'
    },
    templateUrl: "itemfilterTemplate.html"
  }
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'TARS';

  $scope.selectedItems = ["allItems"];

  $scope.items = [{
    "id": "allItems",
    "name": "All Items",
    "order": 0
  }, {
    "id": "CaseItem",
    "name": "Case Item",
    "model": "PredefinedModel"
  }, {
    "id": "Application",
    "name": "Application",
    "model": "Bank"
    }]
});
```

working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/hNui3xgzdTnfcdzljihY?p=preview

**Option#6: Through `$watch` and `$watchCollection`** 
It is two way binding for `items` in all above examples, if items are modified in parent scope, items in directive would also reflect the changes.

If you want to watch other attributes or objects from parent scope, you can do that using `$watch` and `$watchCollection` as given below

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{user}}!</p>
  <p>directive is watching name and current item</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Id:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Model:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="model" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button style="margin-left:50px" type="buttun" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>

  <p>Directive Contents</p>
  <sd-items-filter ng-model="selectedItems" current-item="currentItem" name="{{name}}" selected-items-changed="selectedItemsChanged" items="items"></sd-items-filter>

  <P style="color:red">Selected Items (in parent controller) set to: {{selectedItems}}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

**script app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('sdItemsFilter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '@',
      currentItem: '=',
      items: '=',
      selectedItems: '=ngModel'
    },
    template: '<select ng-model="selectedItems" multiple="multiple" style="height: 140px; width: 250px;"' +
      'ng-options="item.id as item.name group by item.model for item in items | orderBy:\'name\'">' +
      '<option>--</option> </select>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watchCollection('currentItem', function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(scope.currentItem));
      });
      scope.$watch('name', function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(scope.name));
      });
    }
  }
})

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = 'World';

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.items.push({
      id: $scope.id,
      name: $scope.name,
      model: $scope.model
    });
    $scope.currentItem = {};
    $scope.currentItem.id = $scope.id;
    $scope.currentItem.name = $scope.name;
    $scope.currentItem.model = $scope.model;
  }

  $scope.selectedItems = ["allItems"];

  $scope.items = [{
    "id": "allItems",
    "name": "All Items",
    "order": 0
  }, {
    "id": "CaseItem",
    "name": "Case Item",
    "model": "PredefinedModel"
  }, {
    "id": "Application",
    "name": "Application",
    "model": "Bank"
  }]
});
```

You can always refer AngularJs documentation for detailed explanations about directives.

Comment: This worked creating a wrapper function in the `link` method. It was only a problem when I passed the scope function down to another directive from within a directive. The original parent controller function was still called but `arguments` was undefined until I wrapped it like you suggest.

Comment: I had to trigger a fetch from the server so the link function example worked really well for me as I didn't even have to pass data back and forth, just call the ajax function.  You deserve like 3 votes for such an accurate and well put answer.

Answer (score 12):

There are two ways, with which we can call using `&` and `=`.

**If I am using `=` for a scope attribute**, then

```
ng-click='updateparent({person: mandatePerson})'
```

will be changed to

```
ng-click='updateparent(mandatePerson)'
```

---

And in the directive,

```
updateparent="updatePerson()"
```

will change to

```
updateparent="updatePerson"
```

No need to mention arguments here, they will be passed to controller's function definition as a reference.

Using `&` is explained in other answers.

Comment: Thank you, passing the controller's method using '=' is easier to work with than using '&' because I don't have to declare all the arguments in the directive instance

Comment: I've just spent an entire afternoon trying to fix a directive. The problem was the arguments in directive declaration (because they existed the argument passed was undefined).
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another pattern (works in **Angular 1.5**).

```js
angular.module('module', [])

    .controller('MyController', function() {

        var self = this;
        self.msg = 0;
        // implement directive event listener interface
        this.onEvent = function(arg) {
            self.msg++;
        };
    })

    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
          scope: {
            data: '=',
            handler: '='
          },
          template: '<button ng-click="handler.onEvent(data)">Emit event</button>'
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="module" ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
<my-directive handler="ctrl" data="'...received'"></my-directive>
  {{ctrl.msg}}
</div>
```