# Passing variable to directive template without creating new scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to pass variables using attributes to a directive without creating a new scope ?

HTML

```
<div ng-click='back()' button='go back'></div>
```

JS

```
.directive('button', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            button: '@'
        },
        template: "<div><div another-directive></div>{{button}}</div>",
        replace: true
    }
})
```

The problem is that the `ng-click='back()'` now refers to the directive scope.
I still can do `ng-click='$parent.back()'` but it's not what I want.

Comment: you should be using &attr to call parent functions passed as attribute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991137/calling-method-of-parent-controller-from-a-directive-in-angularjs/15991525

Comment: I would like have a generic way. Not `scope: {back: '&'}` if it's what you mean ? To be able to do: `<div ng-click='start_game()' button='Start'></div>` for another example.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

By default, directives do not create a new scope.  If you want to make that explicit, add `scope: false` to your directive:

```html
<div ng-click='back()' button='go back!'></div>
```

```js
angular.module('myApp').directive("button", function () {
    return {
        scope: false,  // this is the default, so you could remove this line
        template: "<div><div another-directive></div>{{button}}</div>",
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.button = attrs.button;
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/gHjU4/)</kbd>

Since a new property, `button`, is being created on the scope, you should normally create a new child scope using `scope: true` as @ardentum-c has in his answer.  The new scope will [prototypially inherit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) from the parent scope, which is why you don't need to put `$parent.back()` into your HTML.

One other tidbit to mention: even though we are using `replace: true`, clicking the element still calls `back()`.  That works because "the replacement process migrates all of the attributes / classes from the old element to the new one." -- [directive doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
 So `ng-click='back()' button='go back!'` are migrated to the first `div` in the directive's template.

Comment: You're right but I need the isolated scope to have multiple buttons with different names. Bad formulated question I guess. http://jsfiddle.net/gHjU4/2/

Comment: OK now I'm feeling dumb, as you said, `scope:true` and no compile needed. I changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should use **compile** function in this case.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive("button", function () {
    return {
        template: "<div><div another-directive></div>{{button}}</div>",
        replace: true,
        scope:   true,
        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            // this is link function
            return function (scope) {
                scope.button = tAttrs.button;
            };            
        }
    };
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/2742/).

Comment: I never used compile before but I saw it in the docs, should of read it. Thanks !

Comment: `scope: true` creates a new scope.  While I think this is the correct way to do it, the OP asked for no new scope.  Also, a compile function is not necessary, only a link function.  See my answer for more info.