# Scope's eval returns undefined in an AngularJS directive

Tags: html, angularjs, callback, directive

Background:
I'm trying to run a callback when something inside the code of a directive in AngularJS happen.

Pertinent code:

HTML:

```
<img-cropper onselect="updateAvatarData" x="100" y="100" src="{{tempAvatar}}" id="avatarCropper"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.updateAvatarData = function(c){
    alert("¡¡¡Funciona!!!!");
};
```

Directive:

```
<<more code up here>>

link: function(scope,element, attr) {
  scope.wsId = attr.id+'WS';
  scope.pvId = attr.id+'preview';
  scope.x = attr.x;
  scope.y = attr.y;
  scope.aspectRatio = scope.x/scope.y;
  scope.previewStyle = "width:"+scope.x+"px;height:"+scope.y+"px;overflow:hidden;";
  scope.onSelectFn = scope.$eval(attr.onselect);

<<more code down here>>
```

The problem is in that last line "scope.onSelectFn = scope.$eval(attr.onselect);". That "scope.$eval(attr.onselect);" returns 'undefined'. The attr.onselect works fine, it returns the name of the function typed on the 'onselect' attribute.

I have made others directives with functions passed via attibutes with no problem, but am unable to find what I am doing wrong here.

- Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try `onselect="updateAvatarData()"`?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Did not work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you are doing like this when u can easily use '&' feature available with angular

[calling method of parent controller from a directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991137/calling-method-of-parent-controller-from-a-directive-in-angularjs/15991525#15991525)

Still if you want to call parent function like this then you should be using $parse instead of eval see a very below small example when using

```
  link: function (scope,element,attrs) {
                   var parentGet = $parse(attrs['onselect']);

                   var fn = parentGet(scope.$parent);
                   fn();

               },
```

Comment: That gave me: "ReferenceError: $parse is not defined". I'll take a look at the link you gave me also. Thanks.

Comment: you have to inject parse in directive definition then it will not give error

Comment: Hehe... of course.... it's an AngularJS service. That woked, but I don't get why it worked the orher way in other directives I did. Sadly I don't have the time right now to investigate. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

`scope.$eval(attr.onselect)` should work.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/dZ4dV/) (tested in Chrome) with a minimal link function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.onSelectFn = scope.$eval(attr.onselect);
    console.log(attr.onselect, ',', scope.onSelectFn);
    scope.onSelectFn();
},
```

The only other thing I can think of is that since [`onselect` is an HTML attribute](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onselect), maybe it doesn't work on some other browsers.  So maybe try using a different attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `$eval` only evaluates the given expression against the current scope.  You can pass in a different data object to evaluate against, and in your case it is the parent scope.  You should call it like this:

```
scope.onSelectFn = scope.$eval(attr.onselect, scope.$parent);
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)