# Angularjs scope.$eval not evaluating

Tags: angularjs, eval

I am using angular 1.5.8 which does not have the ng-keypress, ng-keydown or ng-keyup directives. As such, I am rolling my own keypress event code. I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970876/scopes-eval-returns-undefined-in-an-angularjs-directive) earlier on StackOverflow, and have modified the code to fit into my code by modifying the name of the module and have added debugging alerts to see what's happening:

```
appModule.directive('myEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            alert("Here2");
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                     alert(attrs.myEnter);
                     scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
                 });
                 event.preventDefault();
             }
        });
    };
});

<input type="text" ng-model="zzz" my-enter="alert('Here')"></input>
```

I am seeing the two alerts from the directive code, but the alert which is the target of the directive and which should be evaluated by $eval is not displaying. What is going wrong with this?

Comment: Could you specify which version of angularjs are you using?

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how AngularJS works. I believe that running arbitrary javascript is a security risk and angularJS does not allow that. The $eval is not the same as eval from javascript. It's purpose is to evaluate an expresion in the context of a scope. It's generally used  to expand bindings into concrete values
Consider the following example

```
 app.controller('bobControler',function($scope) {
     $scope.person ={
         name:'bob'
    }
}
```

if I were to call

```
alert($scope.eval('person.name'))
```

this should pop up an alert with the text 'bob'.

To achieve what you want you should provide an input to your directive that is of type &. this is a callback that angular will pass to you and you can call :)

```
app.directive('myenter', function() {
  return {
     restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      myenter:'&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {

        if (event.which === 13) {
          alert("Here2");

          scope.$evalAsync(()=>scope.myenter());
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }

  };
});
```

The full sample is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/0Mb7Ggo72oBAyE60QLWD?p=preview