# Call controller function when directive attribute changed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My code so far:

```
 .directive('ngSpreadsheet', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'EA',
          scope: {
              curpart: '='
          },
          template: '<div id="dataTable" class="dataTable"></div>',
          controller: SpreadsheetController,
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
              scope.$watch('curpart', function (val) {
                  console.log('curpart value changed, new value is: ' + val);
                  // here i want to call a function of the SpreadsheetController 
                  // or is there a better way, executing stuff when an attribute changed?
              });
          }

      }
  })


var SpreadsheetController = (function () {
  ...

  SpreadsheetController.prototype.curPartChanged = function () {
        console.debug('curPartChanged');
    };
})();
```

Comment: you should pass function name as attribute into directive  using '&' feature in directive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991137/calling-method-of-parent-controller-from-a-directive-in-angularjs/15991525#15991525

Comment: is there no better way? I think setting the connection in my html is bad style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth parameter to a `link` function is the controller; I would recommend getting access that way.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller){
    //...
    controller.curPartChanged(...);
    //...
}
```

I can't seem to link directly to the anchor, but [look in this doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) for the section on `LINK`.  You can search for "A controller instance if at least one directive on the element defines a controller" to find the exact section.

**EDIT:**

If you'd like to watch an attribute of a directive, I would consider the `$observe` function, which is very similar to `$watch`.  Head to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/difference-between-observers-and-watchers) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get reference to your controller in your directive, then require your own directive. See: http://jsfiddle.net/7LnrZ/22/

```
var mod = angular.module("myapp", []);

mod.controller("SimpleCtrl", function ($scope) {
    var part = {};
    part.curpart = 1;

    $scope.part = part;

    $scope.increasePart = function () {
        part.curpart++;   
    }
});

var SpreadsheetController = function () {
    console.log("Instantiating SpreadsheetController");    
}

SpreadsheetController.prototype.curPartChanged = function () {
    console.log('curPartChanged');
}

mod.directive("ngSpreadsheet", function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            curpart: '='
        },
        require: "ngSpreadsheet",
        template: '<div id="dataTable" class="dataTable"></div>',
        controller: SpreadsheetController,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) { 
            scope.$watch('curpart', function (val) {
                console.log('curpart value changed, new value is: ' + val);
                ctrl.curPartChanged();
              });
          }
    }
});
```

Compiling order for a directive:

- Directive Controller is called/created
- Directive pre-link function is invoked

  - Child directive(s) of directive controller is created
  - Child directive(s) of directive pre-link is invoked
  - Child directive(s) of directive post-link is invoked
- Directive post-link function is invoked

Answer (score 0):

Communication between a directive and the controller that hosts it **should happen via an event call**. `scope.$emit` will send such an event, while `$scope.$on` will catch events on the other side.

```
.directive('ngSpreadsheet', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            curpart: '='
        },
        template: '<div id="dataTable" class="dataTable"></div>',

        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.$on('curpart.change',function(data){
            console.log('curpart changed.. the new value is: ',data);
        }),

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
            scope.$watch('curpart', function (evt,val) {
                console.log('curpart value changed, new value is: ' + val);
                scope.$emit('curpart.change',val);
            });
        }        
    }
});
```

Comment: I was under the impression that `$emit` and `$on` were for parent-child scope communication, not directive-controller communication.

Comment: I see no reason why one cannot use events to effect communication between different elements within the same scope. In the case of a directive, there is a shared scope between the different parts of a directive - which makes events a great mechanism to communicate between the different parts of a directive.