# angularjs directive data-binding not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive for a dropdown group.
However, the data-binding does not work properly.
**The problem is**: the default variable does not receive value from html, and the item value could not be loaded as well.

Here is the directive code:

```
app.directive 'addquestionbutton', ()->
    restrict: 'E'
    replace: true
    scope:
        default: '@'
        dropdown: '='
        addQuestionClick: '&'
    template: 
        '<div class="bottom-buttons-container">' + 
        '<div class="add-item">' + 
        '<div class="btn-group dropup">' + 
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="btnSelect" ng-click="addQuestionClick(default)">Add item</button>' +
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>' + 
        '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' + 
        '<li ng-repeat="item in dropdown">' + 
        '<a ng-click="addQuestionClick(item)">{{item}}</a></li></ul></div></div></div>'
```

Here is the html code:

```
<addquestionbutton default='Text' add-question-click="addItem(item)" dropdown="dropdownitems"></addquestionbutton>
```

Comment: Since this example is pretty simple, a plnkr to demonstrate would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the parameter inside your function call.  See this related question: [calling method of parent controller from a directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991137/calling-method-of-parent-controller-from-a-directive-in-angularjs)

```
<button ng-click="addQuestionClick({item: default})" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="btnSelect" >
...
<li ng-repeat="item in dropdown">
  <a ng-click="addQuestionClick({item: item})">{{item}}</a>
</li>
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/pqBp4C4x4riwMn5zHa7i?p=preview