# Passing a controller function between directives

Tags: angularjs

I have a set of two directives that call each other recursively to render a tree structure.

I need to pass a controller function reference to those directives so in turn, they need to pass each other that reference.  It seems to work except for the parameters.

Passing the reference to the directive:

```
<item-list items="data" functionreference="controllerfunction(name)"></item-list>
```

Passing the reference between directives:

```
<item-list items="item.children" functionreference="functionreference(name)"></item-list></li>
```

Calling the function:

```
$scope.functionreference({name: name});
```

[Here's a example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/dd001/9jVXZ/14/)

What would be the proper way to declare and pass the function reference?

Comment: What is `name` in `controllerfunction(name)` when used in view?

Comment: I got that from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991137/calling-method-of-parent-controller-from-a-directive-in-angularjs.  You're supposed to pass the function along with the name of the parameters.  Then when you invoke the function, you have to use those names: $scope.functionreference({paramname: value}).  It works in this question's example... but not in mine :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `itemList` template:

```
template: '<ul><item ng-repeat="item in items" item="item" functionreference="functionreference(name)'
```

you reference the function `functionreference(name)`, but you can't call that (you should be calling `functionreference({name:name})` instead.

So, changing your template to:

```
tempate: '<ul><item ng-repeat="item in items" item="item" functionreference="functionreference({name: name})'
```

it should work fine.

**UPDATE:**
The same holds for the appended `<li>` in the `item` directive:

```
<item-list items="item.children" functionreference="functionreference({name:name})"></item-list>
// Instead of: functionreference(name)
```

---

See, also, this **[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/DFE74/)**.

Comment: Updated demo does not work for children when controller function is called. This update has to be done in two places. I should have edited your answer instead. :) @user280767

Comment: Indeed (but you get the point) :) I updated the answer and the demo (just in case someone runs into the same problem).

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure to use **[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/9jVXZ/16/)**. *Make sure the edit is done in two places as shown below.*

Use `functionreference="functionreference({name:name})"` wherever you want to use the controller function inside directives.

```
myApp.directive('itemList', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<ul><item ng-repeat="item in items" item="item" ' +  
                  'functionreference="functionreference({name:name})"> ' + 
                  '</item></ul>',
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            functionreference: '&'
        }
    };
});
```

and

```
$element.append('<li>{{item.name}} [   ' +
                '<a href="#" ng-click="directivefunction(item.name)">directivefunction</a> / ' + // DOES work
                '<a href="#" ng-click="functionreference({name:item.name})">functionreference</a>]' + // Does NOT work
                            '<item-list items="item.children" functionreference="functionreference({name:name})"></item-list></li>');
```