# Send Object From Directive to Parent Controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

How can I send an object back from a directive into the parent controller?

I've defined the following directive:

```
app.directive('inspectorSharedObjects', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      filterText: '=filter',
      type: '=',
      selectObject: '&onSelect'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.dot = function (tags) {
        return "label-dot-" + tags[0];
      }
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    },
    templateUrl: 'partials/InspectorSharedObjectListPartial.html'
  };
});
```

... which I call in the following way:

```
<inspector-shared-objects ng-repeat="group in modelSharedObjects" type="group" filter="filterText" on-select="selectObject(obj)"></inspector-shared-objects>
```

... with the following template:

```
<div class="object-group-header" ng-click="isActive = !isActive" ng-class="{active : isActive}">
  <span>{{ type.name }}</span>
  <span ng-if="filterText">({{ filteredList.length }})</span>
  <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
</div>
<div class="object-group-list" ng-show="isActive">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in filteredList = (type.contents | filter:filterText | orderBy:'name')" ng-class="dot(obj.tags)" ng-click="selectObject(obj)">{{ obj.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

An `ng-click` on the `li` within a list should send the selected `obj` back the parent controller. The above code calls that parent controller's function, but the object I'm trying to pass comes in as `undefined`.

I read through the following question: [calling method of parent controller from a directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991137/calling-method-of-parent-controller-from-a-directive-in-angularjs) - which I think is trying to do the same thing, but I can't see what I'm doing different than the answer (or my interpretation of it).

How can I the `obj` coming from the directive's template passed back up to the parent controller?

**UPDATE**: Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EvilClosetMonkey/7GMEG/

When you click on the bulleted values the console should spit out the object.

Comment: @Mosho, fiddle added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type of binding from one-way to two-way (`&` to `=` in the isolate scope attributes object).

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uLVR6/)

When you use `=`, the object (function here) is passed by reference, so you just pass it by name (rather than as a function call like you had before). Then you can invoke it and all is well.

But when you use `&`, what angular does is wrap what you send in an `eval` and returns a function wrapping that. So your function that you called in each repetition of the `li` element would have been something like this:

```
function(obj){
   return $eval('selectObject("whatever")) 
}
```

And that's why you would get "whatever" logged, no matter what you pass as `obj`.

---

**NOTE:** Since you use a nested `ngRepeat`, each `li` element is 2 child scopes under the controller scope. Calling `$parent.$parent.selectObject(obj)` would also work as a result. You shouldn't do this and it doesn't really pertain to your question, just a friendly reminder as that kind of thing is brought up a lot on angular SO questions.

Comment: Many thanks for solution and extra information, it absolutely helped me see what I was not understanding about `&` vs `=`. +2, if I had the extra! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value of 'group' that you're getting from your ng-repeat.

```
<inspector-shared-objects ng-repeat="group in modelSharedObjects" type="group" filter="filterText" on-select="selectObject(group)"></inspector-shared-objects>
```

Comment: That returns "Category 1", "Category 2", etc... not the specific element the user clicks on.