# Access controller function from directive to update an HashMap

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to call a controller function from a directive in order to update a counter inside an hash-map.

After reading a few solutions, I ended up doing this:

```
'use strict';

var dragDropApp = angular.module('dragDropApp', []);

dragDropApp.controller('DragDropCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.itemCount = {
        'item1' : {
            'count' : 0
        },
        'item2' : {
            'count' : 0
        },
        'item3' : {
            'count' : 0
        }
    };

    //this.updateItemCounter = function(itemId) {
    //    $scope.itemCount[itemId].count++;
    //}
    $scope.updateItemCounter = function(itemId) {
        $scope.itemCount[itemId].count++;
    }
}

dragDropApp.directive('droppable', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : {
            drop : '&', // parent
            bin : '=' // bi-directional scope
        },
        controller : 'DragDropCtrl',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, DragDropCtrl) {
            var el = element[0];

            el.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
                var item = document.getElementById(
                    e.dataTransfer.getData('Text')).cloneNode(true);

                //DragDropCtrl.updateItemCounter(item.id);
           >>>> scope.$parent.updateItemCounter(item.id); <<<<

                return false;
            }, false);
        }
    }
});
```

It works and does what I want, but I don't know if this approach is correct. Is it?

I've also tried to use the controller to access the function **updateItemCounter**, but the hash-map does not get updated, having the same values every time I call the function.

Comment: you may need to call `scope.$apply()` after `scope.$parent.updateItemCounter(item.id);`

Comment: The `scope.$parent.updateItemCounter(item.id);` is already doing what I want. The thing is, am I following the right approach? Or should I follow the approach stated by the answer that you've posted?

Comment: It is not good to use `$parent`. You never know "who is the $parent". Eg. if you do `<div ng-controller="DragDropCtrl"><div ng-if="something"><div ng-if="something2"><droppable/></div></div></div>` function is available on `scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.updateItemCounter` (because `ng-if` creates new child scope). It's better to do it like I described in my answer.

Comment: Ok, then I'll change my code accordingly! Thank you :)

Comment: The best practice is to define callback functions as attributes of a directive as shown in the answer by @akn. Wiring your directive to a specific parent function with `scope.$parent` makes your directive less versatile. Follow the example of `ng-click`. If it called a specific function with `scope.$parent`, how useful would that be?

Comment: Thank you both guys! I ended up changing my code, taking into account the inputs given, and made use of the `$scope.apply()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In html you should set attributes like this:

```
<div droppable bin="something" drop="updateItemCounter(itemId)"></div>
```

In directive if you want to call your controller's function you should call it like this. Note that property name of passed object must be the same as used in html

```
link : function(scope, element, attrs, DragDropCtrl) {
  ...
  scope.updateItemCounter({itemId: item.id}); 
  ...
}
```

if you wold like to pass more arguments you should use in html:

```
<div droppable drop="updateItemCounter(itemId, param2, param3)"></div>
```

and call:

```
scope.updateItemCounter({itemId: item.id, param2: 'something', param3: 'something'});
```

Read these answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997722/1937797
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23843218/1937797

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to bind the **updateItemCounter** function to any attribute. I just want to call it from inside the directive's event listener function.